# Ruby on rails polymorphic model: dynamic fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

Suppose I have base model class `Item`

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :category
end
```

Each category determines which fields should item contain. For example, items in "category1" should contain additional string field named `text`, items in "category2" should contain fields `weight` and `color`. All the fields are of basic types: strings, integers and so on.

These additional values are to be stored in mongodb as document's fields:

```
> db.items.find()                                                   
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d891f5178146536877e1e99"), "category" : "category1", "text" : "blah-blah" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4d891f7878146536877e1e9a"), "category" : "category2", "weight" : 20, "color" : "red" }
```

Categories are stored in the mongodb, too. Fields' configuration is defined at runtime by an administrator.

```
> db.categories.find()                                                                 
{ "_id" : "category1", "fields" : [ { "name" : "text", "type" : "String" } ] }
{ "_id" : "category2", "fields" : [
    {
        "name" : "weight",
        "type" : "Integer"
    },
    {
        "name" : "color",
        "type" : "String"
    }
] }
```

Users need to edit Items with html forms entering values for all additional fields defined for the category of particular item.

### The question is

**What approaches could I take to implement this polymorphism on rails?**

Please ask for required details with comments.

Comment: "Please ask for required details with comments." ? Homework?

Comment: No :) The task is simplified intentionally.

Comment: OK, so this is a 101 version of the Factory pattern. Load object from DB, check "category" and yield object of that type. Ruby and other Dynamic Languages are probably a great fit for this. The problem is, I'm not sure the Rails will actually like this. Does this actually work with ActiveRecord?

Comment: I'm using mongoid, not ActiveRecord. I realize that ruby being dynamic language gives me all tools to construct dynamically typed object. And I'm wondering too whether Rails will like it.

Answer (score 0):

Just subclass the Item, and Mongoid will take care of rest, e.g. storing type.

```
class TextItem < Item; end
```

Rails will like it, but you'll probably want to use #becomes method, as it will make form builder happy and path generation easier:

https://github.com/romanbsd/mongoid/commit/9c2fbf4b7b1bc0f602da4b059323565ab1df3cd6

Comment: I don't know beforehand which fields should the item contain. Each category contains the list of the fields which are available.

Comment: The Category will be, actually, the concrete Class of the Item. Or I'm missing something. Can you provide a real world example of what you're trying to model?

Comment: #becomes was lately committed to Mongoid's master branch, expect it in the next release :)